# How to identify multiple occurrence of a record in string array

Tags: c#-4.0

I have one string[] and its has only 4 possible values like *"www", "xxx", "yyy"* and *"zzz"*.

In a request to my application different combinations of values came in this string[], like:

**Case 1: Single value multiple time:**

```
string[] a = {"xxx", "xxx", "xxx"}; //only "xxx" is present in array multiple times
```

**Case 2: Multiple values single time:**

```
string[] a = {"xxx", "zzz", "yyy"}; //only single value is present for "xxx", "zzz" and "yyy"
```

**Case 3: Multiple values multiple times:**

```
string[] a = {"xxx", "zzz", "xxx", "yyy", "zzz"}; //"xxx" and "zzz" are present multiple times
```

Now, what could be the best possible way to find out that only a single value in coming multiple time or multiple values are coming either single or multiple time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
int count = a.Distinct().Count();
```

And then compare `count` with total values in the array, i.e. `a.Length`. If they are same then every value is repeated once.

`count` contains the number of time a unique value appears in the array.

*Using HashSet*

```
int count = new HashSet<string>(a).Count;
```

However the first approach is recommended.

Comment: Is it possible to this with Hashset<>?

Comment: @Ryan yes and that was my first thought. But it might be overkill if all that is needed is a check for duplicates.

Comment: @ bytefire yes you are right first approach is better than hashset<> for this scenario.